# makepp: how to manage several builds with common source dir?

Tags: c, build, out-of-source, makepp

I have a source tree:

```
/bootloader
/firmware
/system
```

and want to manage two separate builds for *firmware* and *bootloader*, each of them using common *system* sources **but compiles them differently** (i.e. with its own set of options).

Builds must be **out-of-tree**.
Obvious "repository" feature of makepp is not a solution here, because it breaks this principle. Symbolic links are not solution too, because it must work on Windows.

The problem actually is in shared *system* sources, whose relative path structure differs from others, causing common pattern rules not work for them:

```
BUILD_PATH = $(relative_to $(PROJECT_PATH), .)/BUILD/$(relative_to ., $(PROJECT_PATH)) # trick to be able to extend rules for specific files at different subtree levels (if we use Makeppfile for each level)
...
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o : %.c
    ...
```

Approach with single RootMakeppfile and include *.mk files (instead loading them) also doesn't allow me to do something like that:

```
$(BUILD_ROOT_PATH)/*/%.o : %.c
```

I've tried a lot of totally different approaches. It's not such trivial, as it seems to be at first glance. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed how to solve problem.

Solution is to divide Rootmakeppfile project to two Rootmakeppfile subprojects (both loading *../system* makeppfile in its own way), and perform build separately for each subproject (in its own build directory). Project structure with makefiles:

```
/bootloader/
  ...
  BUILD/
  Rootmakeppfile
/firmware/
  ...
  BUILD/
  Rootmakeppfile
/system/
  ...
  Makeppfile
/project.mk
```

Common definitions .mk file should contain following lines:

```
BUILD_ROOT_DIR = $(relative_to $(SUBPROJECT_PATH), .)/BUILD
BUILD_OBJ_REL_PATH = $(BUILD_ROOT_DIR)/$(relative_to ., $(BUILD_OBJ_REL_DIR))
BUILD_OBJ_REL_DIR ?= $(SUBPROJECT_PATH)
```

Each subproject should include *system* as follows:

```
load_makefile BUILD_OBJ_REL_DIR="$(SUBPROJECT_PATH)/.." ../system
```

and define:

```
global SUBPROJECT_PATH := $(abspath .)
```

This approach makes possible to define pattern rules as follows:

```
$(BUILD_OBJ_REL_PATH)/%.o : %.c
```

Hope, it helps someone!